# Selection condition in Eval in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, eval, repeater

This is my td in Repeater.

```
<td>
<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsDiscount")) ? (Eval("DiscountType").ToString() + " " + Eval("Product_Price_Discount").ToString()) : "No Discount"%>
</td>
```

I want a selection condition. 
If `(Eval("DiscountType").ToString() is 1 display "Rupees"`
 else 'Percentage'.

```
ie., if  IsDiscount true, and DiscountType=1  Display.. Rupees-150
  if  IsDiscount true, and DiscountType=2  Display. Percentage-5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a method and do you conditioning in code-behind, like this for example:

```
<%# GetDiscountedPrice(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsDiscount")), Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DiscountType"), Eval("Product_Price_Discount").ToString()) %>
```

and then in code-behind you have a method:

```
protected string GetDiscountedPrice(bool IsDiscount, int DiscountType, string Product_Price_Discount)
{
    return IsDiscount ? (DiscountType == 1 ? "Rupees" : "Percentage") + " - " +  Product_Price_Discount : "No Discount"; 
}
```

With this approach you'l have a more clean HTML in you .aspx

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Uros

Comment: Thanks Uros` for this method.